# Leaving a cell blank until dates are entered

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am using a WEEKNUM formula, and would like the cell to remain blank until there is a date entered.

The formula is as follows:

```
=WEEKNUM(A3,21)
```

I get a return value of 52 when the date column is blank.

Answer (score 2):

An `if` statement inside the cell will work in this case.

inside the cell put this

```
=IF(A3<>"",WEEKNUM(A3,21),"")
```

Answer (score 1):

Use an IF():

```
IF(A3<>"",WEEKNUM(A3,21),"")
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity... Do you know if this formula would behave any differently if the conditional statement was written as A3="" ? How about ISBLANK(A3) ?

Comment: ISBLANK is not an option I like.  If A3 has a formula that returns `""` then it would be false.  It only works on truly blank cells, so whenever I answer, I use `<>""` or `=""` to insure it works either way.  It will work whether there is a formula or not.  @PFitz

Comment: Makes sense. Thx Scott.